# Change document title after ajax call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I would like to be able to set the document title on each page of my React app. While I realise I can use `document.title` I'm not sure how to go about setting the title when it depends on data fetched via an async call. I'm using Redux for the server fetches.

Inside my component class I have:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchJob(this.props.match.params.slug))
}
```

but I'm not sure how to set the title once the call has finished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to set the document title after the call is complete, as with any javascript promise. For more info, have a look at the [**then()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method for Promises:

> The `then()` method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

---

So your code would be:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchJob(this.props.match.params.slug)).then(() => {
    document.title = "Your title";
  })
}
```

Comment: So will I need to adjust my fetchJob function?

Comment: Yeah I have. Getting `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @tommyd456 that means that `dispatch()` returns undefined. Are you sure your original code you posted works?

Comment: Thanks but decided to use `https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title` instead. Seems to do the job.

Comment: `dispatch` doesn't return a promise by default. You have to add middlewares such as `redux-thunk` or `redux-promise`. [Here](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#notes)

Comment: @Ematipico - I do use both of these

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* suggest to use a [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#the-final-approach) (you can create your own one) to manage things like: animations, logging, analytics, etc.

So you won't dirt the logic of your application.

If you want it being part of your application, implement such logic inside your component inside `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentDidUpdate` (I suggest the first one), and update the slug. Of course, you should put a guard in this part of code, a condition of **when to update your title**